# android - disable screen density scaling on alternative devices

Tags: android, scaling

I have a question regarding screen density and layout pixels (not images).

I have a simple relative layout which height I currently set to :

50dp in layout-mdpi
43dp in layout-ldpi

I see that in mdpi everything looks great. However, my ldpi is f***ed up. I see scaling from 43px to 31px which is correct according to .75x scaling. But if I say I want to have a layout file that should render exactly 43dp, why is it still being scaled? I confirmed that I pull different layout files for each device.

How do I turn off that scaling in my ldpi file? I have about 100 layout files to convert and I prefer to keep dps. I know one thing I can do is say "px" instead of "dp". The problem of this device is that its also long. So regilar .75x scaling is not good for us so we need custom sizes for this device. But even if I place this file into 'layout-long' folder with 43dp I still get 32px when I check in photoshop. Which is about 75% of 43.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: is there a global way to cancel out 0.75x scaling on ldpi layout files and drawables? Without me going into every screen and do that?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried renaming the folder to "drawables"? i guess android will resize it automatically. Maybe you could also stick to a standard size closer to each screen size you'd like to make it work. ;)